# Pandas update one dataframe with another

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1:

col1 col2 col3 

A     B    C


df2:
col1 col2 col3 col4
A     B    C    D
```

I want to update df1 with df2 such that if I match on col1,col2,col3, then replace col3 with col4

```
df_want:
col1 col2 col3
A     B    D
```

In SQL, it would be:

```
select df1.col1,df1.col2,coalesce( df2.col4,df1.col3) as col3
from df1 left join df2 on df1.col1=df2.col1 and df1.col2=df2.col2 and df1.col3=df2.col3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `merge`

```
df1=df1.merge(df2,how='left')
df1.col3=df1.col4.fillna(df1.col3)
df1
Out[189]: 
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    A    B    D    D
df1.drop('col4',1,inplace=True)
df1
Out[191]: 
  col1 col2 col3
0    A    B    D
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
del df3['col3']
df3.columns = ['col1','col2','col3']
```

Comment: This is not update , you are using the new column overwrite the old one

Comment: Sorry, I should have also been more explicit. That fixes the problem of dropped entries, but now you need to implement logic to perform the update, so that it keeps the value if nothing merged, but updates if there was a match.

Comment: @ALollz you are right. I just did this based on the data released by the OP.

Comment: I believe that for something more complex, the @Wen-Ben answer will satisfy the OP

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['col1']==df2.ix[index, 'col1'] and row['col2']==df2.ix[index, 'col2'] and row['col3']==df2.ix[index, 'col3']:
        row[C]=df2.ix[index, 'col4']
```

Comment: Thanks, do I first need to do a set_index on col1,col2,col3 on both dfs?

Comment: No, not required!